# utilLocator.findUtil("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil") is undefined

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I am using the below code in ADT custom template code

```
<#assign storageEngineUtil = utilLocator.findUtil("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil") />
```

But this is giving     `utilLocator.findUtil("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil") is undefined`

Is there anything I'm missing here?
but

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The util class `AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil` is not accessible from a Freemarker template.

What you're trying to do is to get access to `AssetEntryLocalService`. Access to Liferay services is restricted in ADT templates.

You can get instance to `AssetEntryLocalService` through `ServiceLocator`, but you have to tell Liferay to allow it.

Default configuration restricts access to `serviceLocator` variable (in `portal.properties`).

```
#
# Set a comma delimited list of variables the FreeMarker engine cannot
# have access to. This will affect Dynamic Data List templates, Journal
# templates, and Portlet Display templates.
#
freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=serviceLocator
```

The setting needs to be overridden to empty value in `portal-ext.properties` (ie. allow the usage of `serviceLocator` in templates).

Then you can finally call `serviceLocator.findService` to get the service.

```
<#assign assetEntryLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalService") />
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas Pinos. My issue is fixed.

Comment: Good. If you like my answer, please accept it. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.